# MVS 3.8 PATTERN DSCB RECORD NOT FOUND IN VTOC

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I'm doing an exercise that requires building a GDG using JCL on an MVS 3.8 system.

I defined a JOB that creates an entry for the GDG ,and created a job to create GDG file.

When I run the JOB to create the GDG file I get the following error
*PATTERN DSCB RECORD NOT FOUND IN VTOC*

I have the entry defined in the master catalog named rsm50.master

[image: master catalog for rsm50]

I also defined the DCB and space for the GDG

is there something wrong in my job file?

My job output from the execution

```
    1     //RSM50C JOB ACC#,'KARAM EX9B',CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=Z,                      JOB   49
          //         REGION=2M,NOTIFY=HERC01,USER=HERC01,PASSWORD=
    2     //STEP1 EXEC PGM=IEBDG
    3     //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
    4     //SUSUT2 DD DSN=RSM50.MASTER(+1),DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
          //          DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=3120),
          //          SPACE=(TRK,(5,5,10)),
          //          UNIT=3390,VOL=SER=MVSCAT
    5     //SYSIN DD DSN=RSM50.JCL.CNTL(EXDATA3),DISP=SHR
```

```
my job code to create GDG entry 
000001 //RSM50B JOB ACC#,'KARAM EX9A',CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=A,              
000002 //         REGION=2M,NOTIFY=HERC01,USER=HERC01,PASSWORD=CUL8TR  
000003 //STEP1 EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                                         
000004 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                          
000005 //SYSIN DD *                                                    
000006  DEFINE GDG(NAME(RSM50.MASTER) LIMIT(4) SCRATCH)                
000007 /*
```

Comment: Can you show the actual message you're receiving ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [reference](https://www.zmainframes.com/viewtopic.php?t=450) to an article that goes into detail on the issue.

The Model DSCB is a reference to a VTOC entry that can be used as a model for a new dataset in a GDG.

Here is a [sample](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=dge-define-generation-data-group-generation-data-set-within-it-non-sms-case-example-1) from IBM's documentation on creating a GDG.

Once created, you can the use this for the reference going forward.  It is essentially used to grab DCB information in the absence of specified information when the new dataset is created.

```
//DEFGDG1  JOB    ...
//STEP1    EXEC   PGM=IDCAMS
//GDGMOD   DD     DSNAME=GDG01,DISP=(,KEEP),
//         SPACE=(TRK,(0)),UNIT=DISK,VOL=SER=VSER03,
//         DCB=(RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=2000,LRECL=100)
//SYSPRINT DD     SYSOUT=A
//SYSIN    DD     *
    DEFINE GENERATIONDATAGROUP -
           (NAME(GDG01) -
           EMPTY -
           NOSCRATCH -
           LIMIT(255) )
/*
//DEFGDG2  JOB    ...
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
//GDGDD1   DD  DSN=GDG01(+1),DISP=(NEW,CATLG),
//             SPACE=(TRK,(10,5)),
//             VOL=SER=VSER03,
//             UNIT=DISK
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=A
//SYSIN    DD  *
/*
```

To your specific case try the following when creating the GDG.

```
//RSM50B JOB ACC#,'KARAM EX9A',CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=A,              
//             REGION=2M,
//             NOTIFY=HERC01,
//             USER=HERC01,
//             PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx  
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=IDCAMS 
//*
//* Note, the following DD name can be anything, it simply
//* allocates the file named which becomes the Model DSCB 
//* for the GDG.
//MYGDG    DD  DSN=RSM50.MASTER,
//             DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//             DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=3120),
//             SPACE=(TRK,0)),
//             UNIT=3390
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                                          
//SYSIN    DD  *                                                    
  DEFINE GDG(NAME(RSM50.MASTER) LIMIT(4) SCRATCH)                
/*
```

Also, you reference SUSUT2 as a DDname.  I think you mean SYSUT2